# Use Microsoft Graph with ASP .NET Identity external authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, microsoft-graph-api

I have a web application using ASP .NET Framework. One its features requires to access to the user’s Outlook calendar.

For the moment, the application uses the regular ASP .NET Identity authentication, without OpenID. It also allows third party authentication providers. Here is the code of my Startup class:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    private static readonly string APP_ID = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Site_Cert_App_ID"];
    private static readonly string APP_SECRET = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Site_Cert_App_Secret"];

    // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        // Configure the sign in cookie
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });            
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        // Enables the application to temporarily store user information when they are verifying the second factor in the two-factor authentication process.
        app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

        // Enables the application to remember the second login verification factor such as phone or email.
        // Once you check this option, your second step of verification during the login process will be remembered on the device where you logged in from.
        // This is similar to the RememberMe option when you log in.
        app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);

        app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(new Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount.MicrosoftAccountAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = APP_ID,
            ClientSecret = APP_SECRET,
            Scope = { "offline_access", "User.Read", "Calendars.Read" }
        });
    }
}
```

As the other features of the application are completely not related to others Microsoft’s services, I’d like to keep this authentication method and use the Microsoft Account external login to use the Graph API, instead of a complete OpendID authentication process. However, I haven’t found any example and I can’t figure out how to access to the token used for the external authentication to reuse it for the Graph API.

Is there a simple way to do it? Or is it impossible and I have to implement the full process to get a token on behalf of user?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user
The steps are the following:

- Register your app with Azure AD.
- Get authorization.
- Get an access token.
- Call Microsoft Graph with the access token.
- Use a refresh token to get a new access token.

Side note, to get a specific user's calendars you can use the

[`GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/calendars`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-calendars?view=graph-rest-1.0#http-request)

[Documentation MS Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview)

[Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I may do that eventually, but I was looking for a shortcut as Identity must already deal with access token in the background when the user uses external login.

Comment: I don't think the token that is used for the first login auth is the same token used for the Graph requests but i could be wrong here. If it is, you could just store that token and re use it, no?

Comment: That is what I am trying to do. The problem is I don't know how, because the external authentification is performed in a black boxe function. I know that in ASP .NET Core, you can set an option to store the token, but it doesn't exist in regular ASP .NET (I haven't found it in at least).

Comment: OK i think i see what you mean, to be sure, you want to get the Graph Baerer Token that you receive on the authentication right and NOT some other Token?

Comment: Yes that's it. However, I saw your response only now. Since my last message, I have implemented the getting of the token on my own via HTTP requests by following the process described in the doc, and it does the job.